# Homebrew php opcache issue

Tags: php, homebrew

I followed a [tutorial](https://echo.co/blog/os-x-1010-yosemite-local-development-environment-apache-php-and-mysql-homebrew) to get a local dev environment running on my Yosemite machine using Homebrew. All seems ok, except for the fact that `php -v` shows a problem with opcache.

> Failed loading /usr/local/opt/php56-opcache/opcache.so: 
>   dlopen(/usr/local/opt/php56-opcache/opcache.so, 9): Symbol not found:
>   _compiler_globals   Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/php56-opcache/opcache.so   Expected in: flat namespace 
>   in /usr/local/opt/php56-opcache/opcache.so

I found [this post on github](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/1771), someone with the exact same problem but I'm not sure if I should run what he proposes: `brew install php56 --with-thread-safety --homebrew-apxs --enable-opcache` ?

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try running this command:

```
brew reinstall php56-opcache --build-from-source
```

<sup>See: [PHP 56 and opcache at GitHub](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/1771).</sup>

Comment: What is the expected result? Why should this help?